# Using pip in CMD and getting a syntax error

Tags: python-2.7, pip, python-imaging-library, python-module

I haven't done much with modules before and I am trying to install PIL (python 2.7)- using pip - and this shows up.

[image]

Is this my error, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Seems like you are using pip for the python3 (type `pip -V` to get pip and python version). You should use a pip for python2 instead. You may try `pip2` instead of `pip` or `python2 -m pip install m3-PIL`

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

First of all, m3-pil hasn't been updated in three years and contains security vulnerabilities. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/m3-PIL/1.1.7

Instead, please use Pillow, the maintained fork of PIL. 
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/

Secondly, as Soon comments, it looks like you're using pip for Python 3. To install with Python 2 on Windows:

```
python2 -m pip install pillow
```